# Doubly Linked List Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

My project is a bubble sort system for doubly linked list.
I am trying to sort elements of doubly linked list (which are objects) by Date.
I used pointer-based sort because I do not want to change the data of pointers.
The problem is my code can (I think efficiently) sort the linked list. But in the end, when I try to print objects of linked list, my head is not in place where it should be. Could you help me?

```
struct DoubleNode *DoubleDynamic::swap( DoubleNode *pointer1,  DoubleNode *pointer2) {
    DoubleNode* temp=pointer2->next;
    pointer2->next=pointer1;
    pointer2->prev=pointer1->prev;
    pointer1->next=temp;
    pointer1->prev=pointer2;
    return pointer2;
}

void DoubleDynamic::sort(int size)
{
    DoubleNode* temp;
    DoubleNode* current;
    bool sorting;
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
        {
            sorting= false;
            temp=head;
            for (int j = 0; j < size-1-i; ++j)
            {
                DoubleNode *employee1=temp;
                DoubleNode *employee2=employee1->next;
                if (employee2!=NULL)
                {
                    if (employee1->data->getAppointment().operator>(employee2->data->getAppointment()))
                    {
                        temp = swap(employee1,employee2);
                        sorting= true;
                    }
                    temp= temp->next;
                }
            }
            if (!sorting)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    current=head;
    while (current->prev!=NULL)
    {
        current=current->prev;
    }
    head=current;
}

void DoubleDynamic::display()
{

    struct DoubleNode *trav;
    trav=head;
    if (trav==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Liste boş yaa"<<endl;
    }
    while (trav != NULL)
    {
        cout<<*(trav->data)<<endl;
        trav=trav->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You'll find answers come quicker if you provide a [mre] (MRE) with your questions. MRE describes a distillation of several powerful debugging techniques, so if you take the building of the MRE seriously, you will probably find the answer yourself and won't even have to ask the question.

Comment: A `<=` in the exit condition of a for loop is usually an off-by-one bug. Make sure `for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)` isn't marching off the end of the list.

Comment: `if (employee1->data->getAppointment().operator>(employee2->data->getAppointment()))` looks clunky. Worth investigating `if (employee1->data->getAppointment() > employee2->data->getAppointment())`.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your comments and advice. I used the overload operator because Date is actually a class and with int day, month and year. But ı checked it in another part. It is working efficiently.

Comment: it's not that you have the operator, it's in how you are using it. It's unusual to see  `A.operator>(B)` invoked. The whole point of operator overloading is so that you can write `A > B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you swap the head pointer, you don't update `head` to refer to the new head node.

One way to address this is after you do the swap, you should check to see if the head pointer should be updated.

```
temp = swap(employee1,employee2);
if (employee1 == head)
    head = temp;
```

Alternatively, in `swap`, if the new `prev` pointer assigned in `pointer2->prev=pointer1->prev;` is NULL then update the head (because the head node does not have a previous node).

```
if ((pointer2->prev=pointer1->prev) == nullptr)
    head = pointer2;
```